# Cabal installed 1.22 but using 1.16 by default how to change?

Tags: cabal, cabal-install

I there i'm trying to install the functionality Sandbox of cabal that comes only with cabal-1.18 .
I use the `cabal install Cabal cabal-install` and even went for `cabal install Cabal cabal-install-1.22.2.0`.

It says i'm using

```
> cabal install cabal
    Resolving dependencies...
    All the requested packages are already installed:
    Cabal-1.22.2.0
    Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

Either way when i do:

```
> cabal --version 
    cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
    using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

It says i'm using 1.16.0. How do I use the 1.22 that was installed?

Comment: `cabal-install` is not the same as `cabal`: the former's a command line tool, the latter's a library on which the former is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cabal install cabal-install-1.22.0.0 --global`

Comment: Thx for the help, I did what u sugested but still not enough, had to force the reinstall of broken pacakges 

cabal install cabal-install-1.22.0.0 --global --force-reinstalls